# Weird accessing SQL data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

This is a rather weird question, and I don't have a title for it.

This is what I'm trying to do, look at this picture :
[image]

I need to access data like this

first_name = Raphael

And I have absolutely no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: what is the condition you want to place ? I mean what do you have with you to retrieve data (where first_name ='Raphael' ) ? or a umeta_id ?

Comment: I need to loop through the entire table and echo out the first_name's

Comment: There is a wordpress function for this, but I can not use wordpress for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT meta_value FROM tablename WHERE meta_key = first_name
```

SHould do the trick!

What we are doing is selecting the value in the meta-value column if the meta_key column says 'first_name'

You can do the same for all fields

```
SELECT meta_value FROM tablename WHERE meta_key = admin_color
```

Would return 'fresh' from your screen-shot.

Comment: Glad I could help - if you wanna + my answer the rep is always appreciated :-D

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get together all/some attributes of user whose first name happened to be `Raphael` then you can do it with conditional aggregation like this

```sql
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name' then meta_value END) first_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'last_name' then meta_value END) last_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'nickname' then meta_value END) nickname,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'description' then meta_value END) description,
       ...
  FROM wp_usermeta
 GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MAX(meta_key = 'first_name' AND 
           meta_value = 'Raphael') > 0
```

Sample output:

```
| USER_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | NICKNAME | DESCRIPTION |
|---------|------------|-----------|----------|-------------|
|      19 |    Raphael |    Landau | enterseo |      (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19a257/3)** demo

Comment: One more thing, how would I go through the entire table and do this?

Comment: Just ditch `HAVING` clause